# Question about a Maclaurin series of an elementary function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

The Maclaurin series expansion for $(1+z)^\alpha$ is as follows:

$$(1+z)^\alpha = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}z^n$$ with $$|z|<1$$

What I don't understand is why is $|z|<1$?

Comment: Your series has an extraneous $1$. The $1$ is the term for $n = 0$, so either remove the $1 + $ or let the summation start at $n=1$. The series has a radius of convergence of $1$ (unless $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$), since the function has a singularity or branch point at $z = -1$

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, the series contains only finitely many nonzero terms, and is hence everywhere convergent.

For $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$, the power function $w \mapsto w^\alpha$ has a pole in $0$ if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$, and for $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Z}$, it has multiple branches (finitely many possible values if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$, infinitely many if $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$). In a small enough neighbourhood of every $w \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, there are holomorphic branches of the power function, but in no neighbourhood of $0$ can a continuous branch of the power function be defined.

So a power series expansion of $(1+z)^\alpha$ cannot have a radius of convergence $R > 1$ unless $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, since a power series defines a holomorphic function in its disk of convergence, and by the above, the disk of convergence cannot contain $z = -1$. On the other hand, a holomorphic function can be expanded into a power series in every disk contained in its domain, so the radius of convergence of the binomial series cannot be smaller than $1$.

So for $\alpha\notin \mathbb{N}$, the power series expansion

$$(1+z)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n}z^n = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} z^n$$

holds in the largest disk with centre $0$ that does not contain $-1$, that is the unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$.